# chrome extension message listener not being called

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

First off, I am very new to chrome extensions so if i miss something silly please point it out to me. I have a content script that has a message listener residing inside, an html page that has the script of the actual message being sent. I get the tab id, url, but cannot get the listener to fire(or so I believe). It has worked 5 random times after tweaking, but not with any consistency.

my popup.html page

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ServerCommunicator.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/util.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/loginPageController.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/managementPageController.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extension.css" />
</head>
<body id="managementPage">

<div id="content">
    <label id="manageLabel"></label>
    <button id="manage" type="button">Manage</button>
    <button id="request" type="button">Request</button>
    <input id="code" type="text" placeholder="request code"/>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

my content script

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action == "test")
        sendResponse({test: "good test"});
});
```

my script loaded inside popup (managementPageController.js)

```
document.getElementById("manage").onclick = function()
{

    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab)
    {
        alert("about to send request. id: " + tab.id);
        // Send a request to the content script.
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {action: "test"}, function(response)
        {
         alert("tab url: " + tab.url);
         alert("sent request: " + response.test);
        });
    });


}
```

and my manifest file

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Getting started example",
"description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "logo.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Inserteck Chrome Extension8"
},
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "http://199.168.255.214:8080/*"
],

"content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["js/background.js"],
    "runs_at": "document_start"
    }
],
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"}
```

I am getting an undefined value back, which i assume is because the listener is failing to be called. If anyone has any input as to a fix or the cause of the issue or maybe if i am simply misunderstanding the use of messages i would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

`sendResponse`(function) becomes invalid when the event listener returns, unless you return true from the event listener to indicate you wish to send a response asynchronously (this will keep the message channel open to the other end until `sendResponse` is called). See the reference: [chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage).

So you have to add `return true;` after `sendResponse({test: "good test"});` to indicate that you will call the response function asynchronously. Like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action == "test") {
        sendResponse({test: "good test"});
        return true;
       }
     return false;
});
```

Comment: I have implemented these changes with no different result. I still receive an undefined value. This may be a stupid question but if returning true keeps the message channel open until sendResponse is called, how can you call sendResponse first?

Comment: Yeah as you said you have to reload the web page again to send request from the extension to the content script.

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassingly, I looked over a different cause since I tested and did not find any reason why this would be the issue. the page must be reloaded or freshly loaded for the extension to inject the content script into the tab's web page. The answer you provided was half of my answer, but I believe the other half was not having a freshly loaded web page when I would rebuild and publish the extension. This seems quite simple now so I hope someone sees this to avoid the simple problems I have encountered.